# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "", while take the code from TFS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type Database, key "". I have not found any solution on Stack Overflow. Can any one help?

Comment: Any code or commands to show us?

Comment: without code sample is hard to find whats wrong.